# Is it worth it to implement both SHA2 and SHA3 at the same time?

Tags: passwords, hash, sha

I'm creating a password storage system for a web server I'm building for fun.

Would it be more secure for me to use both SHA2 and SHA3 for hashing, and then store them in a database? If I use both algos, then I would be able to detect whether or not someone tried to send a SHA2 collision (however unlikely that may be), as the SHA3 hash would be wrong.

But is SHA2/SHA3 so secure that this whole endeavor is entirely pointless?

Comment: don't use plain hashing for password storage. **PLEASE NEVER DO THIS!** Rather go for scrypt, bcrypt or PBKDF2. That being said collisions aren't your concern with passwords but rather second preimages and preimage attacks, which aren't even feasible for MD5/SHA-1/SHA-2/SHA-3

Comment: I think you want to employ SHA-2 or SHA-3 at the  same time or, even more precisely, in the same protocol. I would strongly suggest not *implementing* them at the same time as they are vastly different constructs :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it wrong, and thinking it wrong. The problem with password hashing is not, and never has been, about collisions. The main problems with password hashing are *speed* (hash functions are too fast) and *parallelism* (a hash function is always the same as itself).

There is a lot of theory on password hashing. As an introduction, read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846). The simple one-line summary is: use [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).

Making anything better (i.e. more secure) than bcrypt is hard (some people are [trying](https://password-hashing.net/), and do it the right way: with an open competition, public research, and years of effort). However, making something which is much worse than bcrypt is very easy, and a lot of people achieve just that seemingly effortlessly. By your scheme with a combination of SHA-2 and SHA-3, you would be on the right track to add one more person on the depressingly long list of people who felt that creativity was a good thing in cryptography, and paid dearly for it.

(None of this says anything about SHA-2 or SHA-3 as generic hash functions. But, despite the names, *hashing* and *password hashing* are in fact very distinct activities, do not have the same requirements, and should not use the same algorithms.)

Comment: Why do you recommend bcrypt over scrypt, as the answer clearly states "no scrypt before 2014" - and we live in 2015, even more scrypt has survived 6 years of cryptanalysis and a successor (yescrypt) is finalist in PHC. The only known vulnerabilities are cache-timing (hard to exploit) and a TMTO attack but it's still better than bcrypt IMO.

Comment: PHC exists precisely because scrypt cannot be considered to be the one-and-only answer to such questions. In fact, scrypt was initially designed to support full hard disk encryption: at password hashing time, several seconds of CPU, and gigabytes or RAM, can be devoted to a single hashing operation. For a server that authenticates clients, the conditions are different, and forces a use of scrypt with other parameters (much less CPU and RAM usage) and it is unclear whether this yields a better bargain than bcrypt.